# Nginx config php files from a different server

Tags: php, nginx

I installed [Cachethq](https://cachethq.io/) to have a status page on a server (LAMP) by following this [tutorial](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-cachet-on-debian-8) but I had to use another port (localhost:8080) because I have other services running.

On another server I use Nginx as a reverse proxy to redirect different server/services.

I succeeded to configure Nginx to access cachethq but all the layout does not appear, so I am looking into the fact that I need to redirect php requests to my install server.

I found here several articles and tested different config without success. In addition I would not want these redirects to impact those of my other servers / services.

I'm quite new to Nginx and Php so thanks a lot for your help.

My Nginx config:

```
    location /redmine {
    proxy_pass http://10.160.82.6/redmine;
}

location /MagicInfo {
    proxy_pass http://10.160.82.16:7001;
}

    location /status {
    proxy_pass http://10.160.82.6:8080/index.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass 10.160.82.6:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```